# Asterisk check script not running from crontab

Tags: bash, cron, asterisk

Asterisk check script is not running only when run by crontab, but runs by `./script.sh` and `sh script.sh`. Here is the script:

```
date
asterisk -rx "show channels"
asterisk -rx "zap show channels"
```

Then I `>>` into a log file. When I run manually via `./` or `sh` with `>> log.log` it works, just not as a crontab listed as

`* * * * * /root/script.sh`

I have tried adding `#!/bash/sh` at the top of the script and only the date is shown no matter what I try. I am a noob to bash scripts and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: Have you checked your path? It's almost certainly different when run under cron. (You can set PATH=... in your crontab. From the command line, type "echo $PATH" to see what you're expecting.) It might be more standard to provide full paths to date, asterisk and your log file inside script.sh (e.g., "/bin/date /path/to/asterisk ....")

Comment: ill try that now, why would date work with just date and not the full path

Comment: date works without the full path, now my script works with the full correct path to asterisk, thanks! ill keep this in mind

Comment: Yeah, with date it almost certainly doesn't matter (unless you're using arcane settings and have different versions of date on your machine) but getting in the habit of always providing full paths (or setting your Cron's PATH env) may save you another head-scratching situation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Have you checked your path? It's almost certainly different when run under cron. (You can set PATH=... in your crontab. From the command line, type "echo $PATH" to see what you're expecting.) It might be more standard to provide full paths to date, asterisk and your log file inside script.sh (e.g., "/bin/date /path/to/asterisk ....") – mjk